# MySQL: Find max consecutive rows in a table based on value

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL, I am trying to find the highest number of consecutive rows in a table based on a value. For the sake of simplicity, my table looks like this:

```
+----+-------+
| ID | VALUE |
+----+-------+
|  1 | A     |
|  2 | B     |
|  3 | A     |
|  4 | A     |
|  5 | B     |
|  6 | B     |
|  7 | A     |
|  8 | A     |
|  9 | A     |
| 10 | B     |
+----+-------+
```

In this example, if I wanted the highest number of consecutive rows for 'A', I would get 3. For 'B', I would get 2. Even returning a result set of the counts of consecutive rows for 'A' would be preferable. I am newer to SQL so hints would be appreciated too. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using variables:

```
SELECT VALUE, MAX(cnt) AS maxCount
FROM (
  SELECT VALUE, COUNT(grp) AS cnt
  FROM (
    SELECT ID, VALUE, rn - rnByVal AS grp
    FROM (
      SELECT ID, VALUE,
           @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
           @rnByVal := IF (@val = VALUE,
                          IF (@val := VALUE, @rnByVal + 1, @rnByVal + 1),
                          IF (@val := VALUE, 1, 1)) AS rnByVal
      FROM mytable
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @rnByVal := 0, @val := '') AS vars
      ORDER BY ID) AS t 
    ) AS s
  GROUP BY VALUE, grp ) AS u
GROUP BY VALUE
```

Variables `@rn` and `@rnByVal` are used in order to simulate `ROW_NUMBER` window function, currently not available in MySQL. The second variable (`@rnByVal`) performs a count over `VALUE` *partitions*.

Using `@rn - @rnByVal` in an outer query we can calculate `grp` field, which identifies islands of consecutive rows having the same `VALUE`. Performing a `GROUP BY` on `VALUE, grp` we can calculate the population of these islands and, finally, in the outermost query, get the max population per `VALUE`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3cea/1)

Comment: Thanks so much! That was more complicated than I thought it would be, but it certainly solved my problem.